# Nested Await operations are failing in ..NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I am trying to develop a Windows 8 Metro style application. I have got the following use case:

```
async void dofileop()
{
  await writedatatofile();          
  printdata();
}

IAsyncAction writedatatofile()
{
  readdatafromfile();
  //play with data
  return FIleIO.WriteData();
}

async void readdatafromfile()
{
    await FileIO.readdata();
    operation1
    operation 2
}
```

Here after executing `await FileIO.readdata();`, the control is immediately going to //play with data instead of operation1 and operation2. After executing `printdata()` the control is coming back to operation1 and operation2.

How can I fix these kind of issues?

Comment: quite a bit confusing, could you clarify a bit?

Comment: I am trying to read contents of file and searching for particular string. If the string is found, I will modify that string and write back the data to file.

Comment: As per the usecase all the statements in readdatafromfile() should be executed before control is going back to writedatatofile(). But in reality, imeediately after executing await FileIO.readdata();
 statement, the control is going back to writedatatofile()
without executing the operation1 and operation 2
statements.

Comment: Also my constrain is not to change the syntax of the 
IAsyncAction writedatatofile()
 function.

Answer (score 2):

> As per the usecase all the statements in readdatafromfile() should be executed before control is going back to writedatatofile().

That's not how `async` methods work. You may want to read my [`async`/`await` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). An `async` method will return to its caller when it `await`s some operation that isn't completed (e.g., `FileIO.readdata`).

As a general rule, have your `async` methods return `Task`, and then `await` those `Task`s in other `async` methods, like this:

```
async Task dofileop()
{
  await writedatatofile();          
  printdata();
}

async Task writedatatofile()
{
  await readdatafromfile();
  //play with data
  await FIleIO.WriteData();
}

async Task readdatafromfile()
{
  await FileIO.readdata();
  operation1
  operation 2
}
```

> Also my constrain is not to change the syntax of the IAsyncAction writedatatofile() function.

That's just a bit more convoluted:

```
async Task dofileop()
{
  await writedatatofileAsync();          
  printdata();
}

IAsyncAction writedatatofile()
{
  return writedatatofileAsync().AsAsyncAction();
}

async Task writedatatofileAsync()
{
  await readdatafromfile();
  //play with data
  await FIleIO.WriteData();
}

async Task readdatafromfile()
{
  await FileIO.readdata();
  operation1
  operation 2
}
```